# Restore NTBackup files to Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, restore, windows-2000

I have some NTBackup .BKF files from an old Windows 2000 computer that I'm trying to get restored into a computer running Windows 7. It appears Microsoft does not ship a tool to restore files from such an archive in Windows 7.

If I had physical access to the computer and archive files, this would be a piece of cake, but unfortunately I'm doing this remotely and for all intents and purposes I have no access to any other computer onsite. I could SSH the BKF files to me, but it looks like it'll take a few days and I was hoping to have this wrapped up over the weekend.

Suggestions are appreciated. If there's some 3rd party software that will read these files, I think that'll be easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a bit more googling later, I found this, which I can confirm works.

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-bkf-file-ntbackup-windows-7-vista/

Answer (score 2):

Search for ntbackup restore utility. It is available for Vista and Windows 7. You will find it as KB on microsoft site, free.

I was the MS developer who ported the restore utility to Windows7.